# Speeding up SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I really need help speeding up the following query in SQL Server. Right now I have it as a view but I don't care if it's a view or a function, I just need it to return a recordset to MS Access interface. The query takes 11 seconds to execute but with all of the cycles it goes through I need it down to 3 or less seconds. I've tried to index the view I have now but unfortunately I can't use the AVG function or use a HAVING clause if I am going to index anything.

```
SELECT tblFi.fldFN
    ,tblFc.fldFC
    ,tblFc.fldCity
    ,tblFc.fldState
    ,tblFi.fldIN
    ,tblAPL.fldPK
    ,tblAPL.fldCI
    ,AVG(tblAPD.fldND) AS fldND
FROM tblAPD
INNER JOIN tblAPL ON tblAPD.fldLK = tblAPL.fldLID
INNER JOIN tblUA ON tblAPD.fldUAK = tblUA.fldUAID
INNER JOIN tblUL ON tblUA.fldULK = tblUL.fldULID
INNER JOIN tblFi ON tblUL.fldFK = tblFi.fldFID
INNER JOIN tblFc ON tblFi.fldFAC = tblFc.fldFacID
GROUP BY tblFi.fldFN
    ,tblFc.fldFac
    ,tblFc.fldCity
    ,tblFc.fldState
    ,tblFi.fldIN
    ,tblAPL.fldPK
    ,tblAPL.fldCI
    ,tblAPL.fldPG
    ,tblAPD.fldIG
HAVING (tblAPL.fldCI <> 0) 
AND (AVG(tblAPD.fldND) IS NOT NULL) 
AND (tblAPL.fldPG = 1) 
AND (tblAPD.fldIG = 0)
```

The following are the tables (I only included pseudo names for the columns referenced in the query and then fld1, fld2, fld3 for those that are irrelevant)...

`tblAPL` -- 4.5 million rows, clustered Index on `fldLID`

```
fldLID... INT
fld1... FLOAT
fldCI... FLOAT
fldPK... BIGINT
fldPG... TINYINT
fld2... TINYINT
fld3... TINYINT
fld4... NVARCHAR(15)
fld5... DATETIME
fld6... TINYINT
fld7... TINYINT
```

`tblAPD` -- 12 million rows, clustered Index on `fldDID`

```
fldND... FLOAT
fldLK... INT
fldUAK... INT
fldIG... TINYINT
fld1... SMALLINT
fld2... SMALLINT
fld3... SMALLINT
fld4... NVARCHAR(20)
fld5... TINYINT
fldDID... INT
```

`tblUA` -- 850,000 rows, clustered Index on `fldUAID`

```
fldULK... INT
fldUAID... INT
fld1... NVARCHAR(10)
fld2... INT
fld3... NVARCHAR(15)
fld4... INT
fld5... TINYINT
fld6... NVARCHAR(10)
fld7... INT
fld8... TINYINT
fld9...TINYINT
fld10...TINYINT
```

`tblUL` -- 200,000 rows, clustered Index on `fldULID`

```
fldULID... INT
fldFK... INT
fld1... INT
fld2... INT
fld3... INT
fld4... NVARCHAR(15)
fld5... DATETIME
fld6... DATETIME
```

Comment: *I've tried multiple things, but nothing has helped.* It would be helpful to tell us what you have tried and why they didn't work, before we tell you to look at the execution plans and determine new, suitable indexes OR to use a materialised view so we're not wasting your time ... and ours.

Comment: First of all, what DBMS is this? If MS SQL stands for "Microsoft SQL Server", can you please tell us what the clustered index on each table is?

Comment: Edited it to try to make it a little more clear. The DBMS is MS SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What indexes are on the tables? Can you post your execution plan to show where the bulk of the time is being taken. Not sure it will make much, if any difference but some of your predicates within the HAVING can be moved to the WHERE (those that don't use an aggregate function). Finally, have you tried adding the indexes suggested by SSMS (when viewing the actual execution plan)?

Comment: The first thing I noticed was that you've got no WHERE clause, which means you're grouping the *entire resultset* before you start filtering down to the data you actually want. And some of your HAVING criteria are strictly row-based, unless I'm missing something. Does it help if you move the `tblAPL.fldCI <> 0` and `tblAPL.fldPG = 1` and `tblAPD.fldIG = 0` into a WHERE clause instead?

Comment: Edited to include clustered indexes.

Comment: Just create a temp table load up the Join of APD and APL with the having in there. then use that table to finish the rest of joins you would at least prevent SQL to have to join on couple millions of those records. And try going for WHERE instead of HAVING see @GarethD comment

Comment: @JoeWhite tried that but it ended running 12 seconds rather than 11.

Comment: @JoeWhite: this should not impact performance. A useless clause in `HAVING` can't serve the `HAVING`, so it is treated like a `WHERE` instead.

Comment: @GarethD I ran the execution plan and created every missed index that the server suggested, the query now runs under a second. Thank you very much, I did't even realize the capabilities of using the execution plan.

Comment: Glad I could help. It is useful feature, although the suggested indexes are not 100% so take some of them with a pinch of salt, and remember that every additional index, although speeding up one query will slow down writes as it is more data that needs to be written.

Comment: @GarethD post your suggestion as answer rather than comment.
tripleddev accept his answer as solution after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by adding SET NOCOUNT ON; This should speed it up quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your HAVING clause into a simple WHERE clause?  The only part you really can't move to a WHERE clause is the second line (the one with the AVG statement), right?  This might speed it up since HAVING criteria are not evaluated until the entire resultset is generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tblFi.fldFN
    ,tblFc.fldFC
    ,tblFc.fldCity
    ,tblFc.fldState
    ,tblFi.fldIN
    ,tblAPL.fldPK
    ,tblAPL.fldCI
    ,AVG(tblAPD.fldND) AS fldND
FROM tblAPD (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN tblAPL (NOLOCK) ON tblAPD.fldLK = tblAPL.fldLID
INNER JOIN tblUA (NOLOCK) ON tblAPD.fldUAK = tblUA.fldUAID
INNER JOIN tblUL (NOLOCK) ON tblUA.fldULK = tblUL.fldULID
INNER JOIN tblFi (NOLOCK) ON tblUL.fldFK = tblFi.fldFID
INNER JOIN tblFc (NOLOCK) ON tblFi.fldFAC = tblFc.fldFacID
GROUP BY tblFi.fldFN
    ,tblFc.fldFac
    ,tblFc.fldCity
    ,tblFc.fldState
    ,tblFi.fldIN
    ,tblAPL.fldPK
    ,tblAPL.fldCI
    ,tblAPL.fldPG
    ,tblAPD.fldIG
WHERE (tblAPL.fldCI <> 0) 
AND (tblAPL.fldCI = 1) 
AND (tblAPD.fldIG = 0)
HAVING (AVG(tblAPD.fldND) IS NOT NULL)
```

Make an NON CLUSTERED INDEX over(fldCI) and (fldIG)
Hopefully you have an index for all foreign keys.

Comment: the OP should be aware that NOLOCK opens him up to the possibility of a dirty read.

Comment: yes NOLOCK give you the possibility of dirty reads, but it is faster.

Comment: it's faster for exactly that reason.